# In the mac terminal - how can I get arrow keystrokes from stdin?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, stdin

I'd like to browse a terminal dialog menu with the arrow keys (like bash 'dialog')

I would prefer ruby solution, but bash/python could work.

```
read -n1 input # is not good enough, cause the arrow keys are not regular chars.
```

Also, the 'read' in mac term doesn't support smaller timeout than 1 second.

Anything?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for -

1. a way to simulate key presses to an application, or
2. a way to generate simple dialog boxes, or
3. a way to read characters from a keyboard...

However, these may give you some ideas:

**For 1**: You would probably need to look at the Automator and Applescript

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
   click menu item "New Finder Window" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
end tell
```

**For 2**: You could look at Platypus for generating dialog boxes and wrappers around scripts - available [here](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus)

**For 3**: The following may do something like you want

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Read a key in cbreak mode
stty cbreak -echo; KEY=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null); stty -cbreak echo
#
# If ESCAPE, read next part
if [ $KEY = $'' ]; then
   stty cbreak -echo; KEY=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null); stty -cbreak echo
   stty cbreak -echo; KEY=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null); stty -cbreak echo
   [ $KEY = "A" ] && echo UP
   [ $KEY = 'B' ] && echo DOWN
   [ $KEY = 'C' ] && echo RIGHT
   [ $KEY = 'D' ] && echo LEFT
   exit
fi
echo $KEY
```

I should explain that the `if [ $KEY` line needs to be typed

```
if [ $KEY = $'CONTROL-V ESCAPE' ]
```

i.e. type these 5 things

```
$
single quote
Control V
Escape
single quote
```

Comment: Thank you so much, #3 is what I needed. Modified it a bit since the first 'if' didn't work for me. I check if it's 'non escape' char. My answer is below

Answer (score 0):

According to Mark Setchell, minor modification:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read a key in cbreak mode
stty cbreak -echo; KEY=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null); stty -cbreak echo

# Check if it's a single alphanumeric char
if $(echo $KEY | grep -q -e "[a-zA-Z0-9]"); then
  echo $KEY
  exit
# Else we assume escape char (doesn't cover all cases)
else
  stty cbreak -echo; KEY=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null); stty -cbreak echo
  stty cbreak -echo; KEY=$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null); stty -cbreak echo
  [ $KEY == 'A' ] && echo UP
  [ $KEY == 'B' ] && echo DOWN
  [ $KEY == 'C' ] && echo RIGHT
  [ $KEY == 'D' ] && echo LEFT
  exit
fi
```