# Reading available characters only

Tags: bash, shell

Okay, so I have a script that's listening for some input from a command, and I'd like to be able to manipulate everything that's arrived so far (if anything), but I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible with `read`.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
#!/bin/bash
long_running_task() {
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
        i=$(($i + 1))
        printf '%s' "Task $i "
        sleep 1
    done
}

read_output() {
    status=0
    while [ $status = 0 ]; do
        IFS='' read -rd '' -n 16 text; status=$?
        [ -z "$text" ] && continue

        printf '%s %s' "(${#text})" "$text"
    done
    echo
}

long_running_task | read_output
```

As you'll see, the `read_output` function will only print text when there are 16 characters available (or it reaches the end of input), rather than printing what's available.

Unfortunately I have no control over the output of the long running task, so I can't simply choose a different delimiter. Currently the only way that I can work around this (that I know of) is to have `read` fetch only a single character at a time, but this is horribly inefficient.

Is there any way to have `read`, or something else, fetch as much input as it can then return it, but still offer a means to detect whether the end of the input was reached (as opposed to there simply being no output to capture just yet)?

The environment I'm currently working in is `bash` so I'll accept any bash-specific solutions, but if there are any portable options then I'd love to see those as well. It also doesn't matter how quickly the command returns, provided it does so in a reasonable amount of time (so I can query output every few seconds).

[edit]
Since there's some confusion about the issue, I'll try to give a more functional example:

```
#!/bin/bash
long_running_task() {
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
        i=$(($i + 1))
        printf '%s' "Waiting $i second(s)… "
        sleep $i
        printf '%s\n' 'done.'
    done
}

NL=$'\n'
log() {
    status=0
    while [ $status = 0 ]; do
        IFS='' read -rd '' -n 16 text; status=$?
        [ -z "$text" ] && continue

        printf '%s' "${text/$NL/$NL[$(date +%R)] }"
    done
}

long_running_task | log
```

Still a bit simplistic, but as you can see it takes output from the long running task and processes new-lines adds a time-stamp at the start of lines that need them; it's not perfect but it hopefully gives the basic idea. This isn't what I actually want to do, but I do need to process new-lines and unfortunately this seems to be the only way to do it, but with `read` forcing me to wait it's not responsive enough.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you would need to reduce `16` to some size you are interested in. If that is less than what you would like to print, you could buffer in an array in `read_output` until the chars read satisfy some value and then print the total. You could write each character out to a separate file descriptor (say a temp file) and peek at the temp file if you are interested in incremental values. Just play with the length of `16` until you find something that works for you. You could read every char with `1` if you wanted to.

Comment: Can you give an expected output ,so that it will  be easy to get an insight of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: It seems you need some kind of asynchronous read in bash. Read have a timeout option, you could try to use it with short times for your purpose.

Comment: My answer to another question may help a little... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648228/in-the-mac-terminal-how-can-i-get-arrow-keystrokes-from-stdin/24648728#24648728

Comment: Describe your task. Why can't you wait until the process writes all 16 cars? Maybe you could run read by separate process, which will send signals to main process when data is ready.

Comment: The question is unclear. You want to "manipulate everything that's arrived so far" but reading one character at a time is "horribly inefficient"? *How are you going to manipulate something you don't know? And running 16 `read` commands is not exactly time consuming, unless you need to do it repeatedly. [What are you actually trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: The long running task is just returning arbitrary, unstructured output that I want to be able to pass on with some minor processing. For example, say it prints 'Waiting for timer…' (no new-line) and after a while it finishes with 'done.' (and a new-line). I don't want to have to wait until the 'done.' to begin passing on the processed text, but if I use a read with a target of 16 characters I'll get 'Waiting for time' and then be forced to wait indefinitely with no way to get the final 'r…' of the initial output. I'm not doing anything that requires structure, but it needs to be timely.

Comment: I've added a more functional example hopefully better showing the problem; it's a basic logging tool looking for new-lines and adding a time-stamp to them, but the blocking in `read` will limit how responsive it is when dealing with incomplete output (i.e - while long_running_task is sleeping).

Answer (score 1):

@Haravikk: your question relates closely to mine **[here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010208/redirect-pipe-into-read-command/26030392?noredirect=1#comment40881696_26030392)**

Unfortunately many experiments and the only answer I got from @chepner lead me to think that there is no easy way to make `read` do what it wants to do. It seems that `read` can only swallow chunks of text in three ways:

- after it gets a newline (or another custom separator, at least in zsh)
- after a predefined number of chars
- after a predefined timeout

PS: it makes sense that `read` wouldn't take *whatever arrived so far*: imagine that your `read_output` function does string substitution, e.g. `sed "s/Hello/World/g"`, and that your task yields `Hel` and after a long time `lo`. Reading the output in chunks would miss the substitution, which would probably be contrary to the purpose of `read_output` ; catching the substitution would imply to take chunks as they come (based on some time-based or number-of-chars-based algorithm) but also concatenating and parsing previous chunks, in which case you'd probably need a proper parser rather than plain `read` ...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've had to settle for a compromise; although I want to avoid reading single characters it seems to be the only option to avoid `read` suddenly blocking data that's arrived.

So my solution looks like the following:

```
log() {
    status=0; new_line=1
    while [ $status = 0 ]; do
        IFS='' read -rn 1 char; status=$?
        if [ -z "$char" ]; then
             [ $status = 0 ] && { printf '\n'; new_line=1; }
             continue
        fi

        [ $new_line = 1 ] && { printf '%s' "[$(date +%R)] "; new_line=0; }
        printf '%s' "$char"
    done
}
```

This is for the pure shell version, and actually should work in most shell environments (not just bash, unless I've missed something). Of course for outputting to stdout it's fine, but if this is to be adapted for output to a file then it should either be piped through `tee` or the `printf` statements need to be directed to a file-descriptor, otherwise it is incredibly slow (since it'll re-open the file for every character).

Of course other languages like `python` and `perl` may be better solutions overall, and I'll use them where available, but this will need to be my fallback. I think I'm also going to make its usage optional, so that it is only used for scripts that expect partial input from some of the programs they run.